# How to properly use a method of another class? (Basic Calculator) (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have made a main class and a another class (which is a basic calculator). But when I try to call it from my main class gives me an error. Can anyone please give me a solution. I am coding in eclipse.

**This is my main:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiClass {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Calculator.calculatorObject = new Calculator();
        calculatorObject.Addition();

    }

}
```

**And this is my calculator class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public void  Addition(){

        Scanner takeValue = new Scanner (System.in);

        double num1, num2, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
        num1 = takeValue.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
        num2 = takeValue.nextDouble();

        answer = num1 + num2;

        System.out.println("your answer is: " + answer);


    }

}
```

Comment: **What** error? Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: thanks for replying, this is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 calculatorObject cannot be resolved or is not a field
 calculatorObject cannot be resolved

 at MultiClass.main(MultiClass.java:7)

Comment: You don't declare your calculator variable correctly. Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: I am still new to this and I can only learn through examples. Could you please give me some sort of example so that I may properly understand?

Comment: Sorry, that's not how this site works.  You are expected to put forth significant effort yourself, and that includes reading tutorials and documentation.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: Well, the second line in the linked page shows how to declare and initialize a variable: `int cadence = 0;`. So it's "type" followed by a space, followed by the variable name, followed by =, followed by the value. Your code has type followed by a dot followed by a variable name.

Comment: I appreciate the comment Jim, but with al due respect I can only learn through example, that's how it is. And I do put in effort, Its not like I am asking answers out of the blue. I have added my own code and I keep planning to. And if it is edited I can understand how it works.

Comment: JB Nizet, I will have a look at the code now. Thank you for the reply, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not initialize the calculator object properly. You made it act like a parameter in the Calculator class instead of making it a parameter in your main class.

You should put this line:

```
Calculator calculatorObject = new Calculator();
```

Instead of this line:

```
Calculator.calculatorObject = new Calculator();
```

Initializing means that you want to give an object that you declared a value.
Let's say that you declare an integer and call it i

```
int i;
```

But you want to initialize it too, because right now it has an empty value:

```
i = 89;
```

Or by intializing it right after declaring:

```
int i = 89;
```

Comment: Thank you so much binary lord fir pointing that out. A while back I deleted the code and re wrote it again but this time it worked. I couldn't put my finger around it but it seems it was the accidental ( . ) that messed it up. The way you explained it gave me a more clearer idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize your Calculator object properly.
The code should be:

```
  public class MultiClass {

public static void main (String args[]){

    Calculator calculatorObject = new Calculator();
    calculatorObject.Addition();

}
```

}

Comment: @SparkKiddo It should run. No need to remove anything, just initialize the object properly as I mentioned.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 calculatorObject cannot be resolved or is not a field
 calculatorObject cannot be resolved

 at MultiClass.main(MultiClass.java:5)

Comment: by initialize what do you mean?

Comment: Check my answer above in main class, do you see the line Calculator calculatorObject = new Calculator();

Comment: Why did you remove the scanner tho, just change your MultiClass class to the program above, no need to remove the scanner.

Comment: By initialize, he means that you didn't create an object properly.

Comment: @SparkKiddo Read sun or oracle Java docs, it will enhance your java skill as u mentioned you are new. Thank you.

Comment: alright, thank you all for your help. I understand I am new to all of this so please bear with me. I will do my best.